# How to pass a rectangles handle in matlab from one method to another?

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm using OOP in Matlab to make a player made up of rectangles. I want the rectangles to move when pressing a key, so I made a class for handling the player. I can the rectangle drawn but I am unable to move at all with just a method. Instead I get the error "Undefined function or variable 'PlayerShaft'." I think I am either passing or saving the rectangle wrong. I thought it's handle would be saved locally by the class so that I could access it and alter it but that does not seem to be the case. I've looked up how Matlab handles classes but I can't seem to find any information on this particular problem. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code so far:

```
classdef Player

    properties

        axesWidth = 100;
        axesHeight = 100;
        ShaftPosX = 50;
        ShaftPosY = 50;
        ShaftWidth = 10;
        ShaftHeigh = 20;
        BallOffset = 5;

    end

    methods
        function obj = Player()
            PlayerShaft = rectangle('Position',[obj.ShaftPosX obj.ShaftPosY obj.ShaftWidth obj.ShaftHeigh],...
                'Curvature',1,...
                'FaceColor','r',...
                'Visible','on');

            disp('It is on');
            disp(obj.ShaftPosX)

        end

        function DrawPlayer(obj)

            for i=1:20
                obj.ShaftPosX = obj.ShaftPosX +1;
                set(PlayerShaft,'Position',[obj.ShaftPosX obj.ShaftPosY obj.ShaftWidth obj.ShaftHeigh]);
                %PlayerShaft.Position = [obj.ShaftPosX obj.ShaftPosY obj.ShaftWidth obj.ShaftHeigh];
                pause(0.1);
                disp(obj.ShaftPosX)
            end
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: Why do you expect `PlayerShaft` variable in the constructor to be saved by the class once the constructor finishes ? `PlayerShaft` should be made a property of the class and should be used like `obj.PlayerShaft = rectangle...` and then in your draw method you can use `set(obj.PlayerShaft,...`

Comment: Also, if you wish to have pass-by-reference semantics, which is implied by the lack of a returned `obj` in `DrawPlayer()`, you should inherit from `handle`.